# Maven Dependency Issues with spring security library

Tags: maven, spring-security, dependency-management

I do have query regarding dependency in Maven.

In project A, I am having spring-security dependency with version 3. Version 3 is required as this project is using classes of version 3 library.

In project B, I am having spring-security dependency with version 4. Version 4 is required as this project is using classes of version 4 library.

Now I want to use some of the classes of Project B into Project A.
When I add dependency of project B into project A's pom.xml. Project build successfully but on the deployment server is throwing exception for the spring-security library conflicts.

Is anyone faced the same issue in past?

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude any libraries you don't want to import from project B when defining dependency in project A, e.g.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        ...
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

You can see what all libraries are imported as transitive dependencies from your project B by running commadn "mvn dependency:tree" and populate your exclusions based on it.